# How can I loop through an array in an ordered way getting the index?

Tags: python

I have two arrays that are ordered. How can I loop through the first array and get the index of the current element so I can access the respective value of the second array?

Comment: [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)?

Comment: What makes you say it's not doing it in _the right order_?

Comment: Now the question is vague. What do you mean by `doing it in the right order!`?

Comment: It was doing in the right order, I just read it wrong. Just updated the question so it's not vague anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function, like this

```
for index, value in enumerate(first_list):
    print second_list[index]
```

Comment: @fromvega Please explain with an example.

Comment: I will recheck my code and I will get back to you! Thanks!

Comment: That is right, it _is_ doing in the right order. My mistake!

Answer (score 1):

```
In [192]: L1
Out[192]: [-2, 4, 3, -1, 2]

In [193]: L2
Out[193]: [-1, 5, 4, 0, 3]

In [194]: for i,num in enumerate(L1):
   .....:     print(num, L2[i])
   .....:     
-2 -1
4 5
3 4
-1 0
2 3

In [195]: for num1, num2 in zip(L1, L2):
   .....:     print(num1, num2)
   .....:     
-2 -1
4 5
3 4
-1 0
2 3
```